# tcp_keepalive_time less than 2 hours

Tags: linux, networking, amazon-ec2, tcp, akka

The RFC says:

Keep-alive packets MUST only be sent when no data or acknowledgement packets have been received for the connection within an interval.  `This interval MUST be configurable and MUST default to no less than two hours(7200 seconds)`

What happens if keepalive interval set to something less than 2 hours? for an instance 60 seconds(1 minute). It will detect the remote peer dead/closed after `60 + tcp_keepalive_intvl * tcp_keepalive_probes` seconds. But will that causes resource drain(for an instance battery drain on mobile device)

Comment: try it and see what happens

Comment: My question is about resource consumption(for an instance battery drain on mobile device).

Comment: Same answer. You would gave to try it. Obviously it will consume more battery, but only you can determine how much. Your question cannot be answered *a priori.*